# Troubles with the Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm having a problem with th following code. The error is:

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, spanish]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite} %referencias
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %alineamineto %\begin{center,flushleft,flushright} %endtal y cual
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Ambos para solución de asuntos de idioma
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %letra en color
\usepackage{tocbibind} % Bibliografía en el indice
\usepackage{titlesec} % Posibilidad de editar los formatos de chapter
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs} % Matemáticas varias
\usepackage[margin=1cm,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} %los pies de pagina se pegan al fondo de la página
% Arreglos varios para la inclusion de imagenes
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}  
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg,.pdf,.mps,.gif,.bmp}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Administrador/OneDrive/Temasuni/cuarto/TFG/Texto/Fotos/}}
%\graphicspath{{/Users/dani/SkyDrive/Temas uni/3º/Primer Cuatrimestre/Laboratorio de optica/Práctica 6/Graficos/}}
% Para las dimensiones de los márgenes etc
\frenchspacing \addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{3cm} \addtolength{\voffset}{-2.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4cm}
\topmargin 2cm
% Para el encabezado
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[R]{07/10/2016}\fancyhead[L]{Encabezado} \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%-- Definir el numero de las secciones a mi estilo.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textit{\arabic{section}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textit{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\textit{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\textbf{\arabic{equation}}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{huge}
                \vspace*{\fill}

                %Aqui va el titulo

            \end{huge}
            \rule{80mm}{0.1mm}\\
            \rule{80mm}{0.1mm}\\

            %nombre
            \vspace{7pt}

            \vspace*{\fill} 
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

    \tableofcontents
    \pagebreak
    \section{Abstract/Resumensicoh}
    \section{Introducción teórica}
    \subsection{Objetivos}
    \subsection{Desarrollo del trabajo}

    A la hora de estructurar este trabajo he querido seguir un método inductivo, comenzando por una explicación de todos los conceptos hidrológicos, tecnológicos y geoestadísticos que se van a utilizar para el desarollo de los objetivos. Tendremos tres partes diferenciadas: la física del agua en el suelo, en concreto, el contenido de agua del suelo (humedad) como variable fundamental; los métodos geoestadísticos necesarios para la validación y, finalmente, la herramienta donde los tenemos implementados: ArcGis. Posteriormente expondremos como son nuestros datos y qué tratamiento les  hemos dado. Finalizando con una exposición de los resultados obtenidos y las conclusiones obtenidas.


    \subsection{Introducción a la física del suelo}

    Debido a que  el objetivo principal de este trabajo es validar medidas de humedad  del suelo, merece la pena dar un esbozo del enfoque físico que se le puede dar al comportamiento del agua dentro del suelo y, en concreto, el vital papel juega la humedad del suelo para su estudio. Con mucho más detalle  se explica en \cite{SP} y 
    %Está es una parte del sistema complejo que es el suelo 

    \vspace{15pt}

    La primera pregunta qué hemos de contestar es qué entendemos por suelo y qué papel juega el agua en él. Como sistema físico el suelo es una mezcla de sustancias en los tres estados de la materia, es un sistema de tres fases, cada una de ellas fundamental para su otorgarle las propiedades extraordinarias  que presenta.

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Fase sólida.} En estado sólido se encuentran tanto minerales de diferentes tamaños y composiciones como  materia orgánica (residuos en estado de descomposición y organismos vivos).Desde un pyunto de vista físico dicha parte sólida está formada por partículas individuales que llamamos 'texturales' que  se agrupan en pequeños gránulos de  diferente tamaño \footnote{Desde el límite del tamaño coloidal  $10^{-5}-10^{-9}$ m hasta partículas del orden de los centímetros} que  son lo que conocemos como unidades estructurales de suelo \cite{SP}. Estos gránulos se encuentran separados unos de otros, dejando unos intersticios de tamaño también variable. Es en dichos intersticios es donde se pueden alojar la fase líquida y sólida del suelo. 

        \begin{figure}[htb]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics{a.jpg} % include ./img/imagen.[pdf|png|jgp] si es pdflatex o ./img/imagen.eps si es latex7

            \end{center}
            \caption{Esquema medidas osciloscopio}

            \label{medidaosci}
        \end{figure}

        La clasificación que se hace de los suelos atiende al tamaño de dichos gránulos y  la composición en marteria orgánica de estos:

    \item \textbf{Fase líquida.} n

    \item \textbf{Fase Gaseosa}n
        \end{itemize}

    \subsection{Humedad del Suelo. Medida}

    \subsubsection{Métodos \textit{in situ}}
    \subsubsection{Métodos Telemáticos: SMAP y SMOS}


    \subsection{Geoestadística. Métodos de Interpolación Espacial}

    \subsubsection{IDW}
    \subsubsection{Krigin}
    \subsubsection{Vecino Natural}
    \subsubsection{Krigin}
    \subsubsection{ArcGis}

    \section{Tratamiento de Datos}

    \section{Resultados}

    \section{Conclusiones}


    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\cite` and `\natbib` packages at the same time.. Use one or the other. And you loaded `\graphicx` twice. Just once with the options passed to it will do.

Comment: Welcome. Please reduce your example to relevant parts. Your error message is very clear for me. `acm` doesn't work with `author-year` of `natbib`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I reduced your given code to be minimal.  With the following MWE (see the commented package `natbib` please!)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, spanish]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Ambos para solución de asuntos de idioma
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cite} %referencias
%\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use the bibfile created by filecontents

\end{document}
```

I can compile the code without errors with your used style `acm`. And get the result

[image: resulting pdf]

Please not that style `acm` and `natbib` can not be used together!